# Change exposed WebService URL in Wildfly

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, wildfly

I have a webapplication currently working under **Glassfish 4.0** and want to modify it to work under Wildfly 8.2. The problem I currently have is:

I have some Webservices (with annotation `@WebService`) wich currently are published under `/ws/`

f.e. "PanelService" would be exposed under `/myAppContextRoot/ws/PanelService`

I did this by binding the `Glassfish-WS-Servlet` (ergo JAXWS-RI) to  `/ws/*`  in `web.xml`.
Is there a comparable way for **Wildfly** preferable without using **Wildfly** specific annotations - just by configuration? I don´t want to have `jboss-classes` in my `classpath`.

My current "solution" is to add `JAXWS-RI` to the classpath and publish the services two times - by `JBoss-WS` and `JAXWS-RI` :-(

€edit:

The solution of *Terrence Curran* actually works..... but.... I had to add minor changes.

- What I didn´t know: had to place the file under `src/main/webapp/META-INF` (Maven Web project) - tried `src/main/resources/META-INF` before...
- the context-root had to contain my app-name..... my `jboss-webservices.xml` is now:

.

```
<webservices>
    <context-root>myApp/ws</context-root>
</webservices>
```

- I had to mark at least *one* of the webservices as `@Stateless` EJB. Don´t ask me why - but if I remove the annotation the file doesn´t seem to get parsed and applied. Only if there is one WS present also as EJB my wildlfy will apply the `jboss-webservices.xml`. (Bug?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also look at defining the context-root in a jboss-webservices.xml file. This way you can avoid modifying your web.xml which will break your deployment in GlassFish.

```
<webservices>
    <context-root>ws</context-root>
</webservices>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it.

Under Wildfly it´s possible to map WebServices as "servlets" in the `web.xml`.
So I just had to remove `JAX-WS RI` and add the following snippet to `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PanelService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.myapp.ws.PanelService</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PanelService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/PanelService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

@cljk nice shortcut.

To complete your answer, if you don't want to mess with web.xml, `@WebServlet` annotation will work too:

```
@WebServlet("/soap/test")
@WebService(name = "test", serviceName = "testService", portName = "testPort")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
@MTOM(enabled = true, threshold = 4194304)
public class SoapTestService
{
    ...
}
```

and you'll get:

```
JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=it.shape.myapp.ws.soap.test.SoapTestService
 address=http://localhost:8080/myapp/soap/test
 implementor=it.shape.myapp.ws.soap.test.SoapTestService
 serviceName={http://test.soap.ws.myapp.shape.it/}testService
 portName={http://test.soap.ws.myapp.shape.it/}testPort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=true
```

tested on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final